# why doesn't my doIf code block execute even if explicitly set the condition to true?

Tags: conditional-statements, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

This is the Gating performance test code written using Gating Scala DSL.

I need the **randomSwitch** to run 50% of the time if the value of the flag : **makeATP1value** which is a **boolean** value set to true. What I fail to understand is - why wouldn't the **doIf** condition evaluate to "**true**" and program run the **randomSwitch** code block. Can someone review and correct what i may be doing wrong here please?

Following is the code snippet:

```
def submitConfirmOrderAnonymous = group("ATP1 Calls") {

    val makeATP1value : Boolean  = true

    doIf(makeATP1value){
      randomSwitch(50.0 -> exec(PurchaseFalabella.makeAtp1CallBeforeSubmitConfirmOrder))
    }

exec(Purchase.submitConfirmOrderAnonymous)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `.` (dot) to chain the `doIf` and the `exec` so only the last instruction of the block (the `exec`) is passed to `group` and the rest (the `doIf`) is dropped.

Comment: If i add a . (dot) to chain it to the group, then a compiler error is shown; ' } ' expected
I'm bit lost here on what's the correct way to chain the request
```
object PaymentChainBuilder {

  def submitConfirmOrderLogin = group("ATP2 Calls"){

    .doIf(makeATP1){
      randomSwitch(
        100.0 -> exec(PurchaseFalabella.makeAtp1CallBeforeSubmitConfirmOrder))
      // New API makeATP1 call
      // FalabellaConfig.makeATP1Percentage -> exec(PurchaseFalabella.makeAtp1CallBeforeSubmitConfirmOrder))
    }
exec(Purchase.submitConfirmOrderLogin)
  }
```

Comment: The dot is to be placed before the `exec` to attach it with the preceding `doIf`.